# PHP - Decrypt - OpenSSL

Tags: php, encryption

The encryption is done correctly, but when to use `openssl_get_privatekey` and save in `$key_resource`, this has a null value, so it throws the error: `openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key in ...`

```
    function encriptarDatos($datos){
        $fp=fopen("public.key","r"); 
        $pub_key=fread($fp,8192); 
        fclose($fp); 
        $key_resource = openssl_get_publickey($pub_key); 

        openssl_public_encrypt($datos,$encriptado,$key_resource ); 
        /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
        return(base64_encode($encriptado));
    }

function desencriptarDatos($datos){
        $fp=fopen("private.key","r"); 
        $priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
        fclose($fp); 
        echo "priv_key: $priv_key <br/><br/>";
        $key_resource = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
        echo "key_resourse: $key_resource";

        openssl_private_decrypt($datos,$desencriptado,$key_resource); 
        /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
        return(base64_encode($desencriptado));
    }
```

Then I changed it:

```
        $fp=fopen("private.key","r"); 
        $priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
        fclose($fp); 

        openssl_private_decrypt($datos, $desencriptado, openssl_pkey_get_private($priv_key, "phrase"));
        /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
        return(base64_encode($desencriptado));
```

but the result is also null

Comment: If it's not a valid private key, then it's not a valid private key. No one can verify if the path is correct or if the string is really a private key so nothing can be done.

Comment: Open your private key in binary mode and make sure your file handling is correct before trying to parse the data. Please post a test private key in hexadecimal format if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Code: http://hastebin.com/unojijetuy.xml

OutPut: 

'Datos: Esto es una prueba

Encriptado: J+bDIT8JhqbwWfiSg7vM2TUgEfDweX1cj8ai5qviT7vsAJRARyR5DnM0cs1KZLoFJgZacFOYcgftOJJP/+ExwHRum33sPkQnTE32V/f2b2UBHHSROCwmh5t9WBDYaR3RRW1AGsDroOgEtEoCRgcIcfGzmy0+37IMlHji15T33Z3+4+rpoBQXB8q72YmCPcCLdZOoe+QV6cOs2kiSGdjgjk8Sy/czw0Gc6k/TsuB+msVMBVcbqjczU6pSgEdKD//NReBgyHU+npTw9XLXocNQnJSjk61RBJQHI620vp9wK9gxiGM4GT9xudzaz5Lm91jRRGZqwVwMzkJievxiqSWF1g== 

Desencriptado:'